# how do i Unstake my eth valididator node from allnodes?

Tags: validators

I hosted with Allnodes, I want to know if I can get just the rewards out or unstake the whole thing and how to do it, please!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwwZjD96vuU
I found this video helpful but it looks like it is not going to been soon.  it limits the amount that can be opened and closed in a block.  This will only happen after shanghi upgrade which should be soon.  Wish I knew more. To summarize there will be a que to withdraw and open validator, around 424 a day with around 300k validators active I imagine many are needing to liquidate.  I suspect increased sell pressure, and wanted to minimize impact, but this video explains it much better.  I do not know the exact action path yet.

Comment: I too have allnodes validator.  So will follow thread, if I find out anything more I will update, please do the same.  Peace